# NSTimer auto-invalidation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

How long does it take before the NSTimer auto-invalidates itself when using a timer with repeats:NO. 
Could this be a false alert when running the profiler for leaking?

When I have made a server request, I get a success or a failure. Either way I create a new timer

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateSystems) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

When the timer fires, the application makes a new server request.

Comment: Is your question - 'help, I have leaks when using a timer?' - if so, post your timer code! (And if you're testing with the simulator, _dont_, it will give you false positives - test on a device)

Comment: No I was just wondering how long it will take before the actual timer auto-invalidates. The timer code is nothing advanced. But I can post it if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timer will invalidate after the time interval you set has been reached and it has no further loops to execute. So if you set `repeats:NO`, it will invalidate itself.

I think that the leaks aren't in `NSTimer`, but in the selector it executes instead, which is handled by you. Use Xcode's Analyzer Tool (CMD-Shift-A) to find where the leaks are and/or check that you release whatever you `alloc` & `retain` in that selector.

`NSTimer` is innocent. :)

Answer (score 0):

The timer will be invalidated after it fires (after the time interval u have given).

See [ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Also, inside the selector that is invocated by the timer, the code block should be covered with NSAutoreleasePool.

The selector method should be like this.

```
-(void)timerMethod:(NSTimer*)timer
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  ....
  [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Covered with NSAutoreleasePool, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Not particularly necessary. Deal with normal retain/release cycles where possible. In most cases, auto release pools are unnecessary and unnecessarily resource consuming.